# How to select combinations of years and months in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with a SQL query where I need to find all possible combinations of years and months that interest me. Here is my take on it where the `o.orderdate` is of type `DATETIME`.

```
SELECT 
    o.orderdate
FROM
    Sales.Orders o
WHERE  
    (YEAR(o.orderdate) IN (2007, 2008))
    AND (MONTH(o.orderid) IN (1, 2, 3))
ORDER BY 
    o.orderdate;
```

What I get is as a result is this where we can see that the months are not selected.

```
2007-07-08 00:00:00.000
2007-07-09 00:00:00.000
2007-07-09 00:00:00.000
2007-07-10 00:00:00.000
2007-07-11 00:00:00.000
2007-07-11 00:00:00.000
2007-07-14 00:00:00.000
2007-07-15 00:00:00.000
2007-07-16 00:00:00.000
2007-07-16 00:00:00.000
2007-07-17 00:00:00.000
2007-07-18 00:00:00.000
2007-07-18 00:00:00.000
2007-07-21 00:00:00.000
2007-07-22 00:00:00.000
2007-07-22 00:00:00.000
2007-07-23 00:00:00.000
2007-07-24 00:00:00.000
2007-07-25 00:00:00.000
2007-07-25 00:00:00.000
2007-07-28 00:00:00.000
2007-07-29 00:00:00.000
2007-07-29 00:00:00.000
2007-07-30 00:00:00.000
2007-07-31 00:00:00.000
2007-07-31 00:00:00.000
2007-08-01 00:00:00.000
2007-08-04 00:00:00.000
2007-08-05 00:00:00.000
2007-08-05 00:00:00.000
2007-08-06 00:00:00.000
2007-08-07 00:00:00.000
2007-08-07 00:00:00.000
2007-08-08 00:00:00.000
2007-08-11 00:00:00.000
2007-08-11 00:00:00.000
2007-08-12 00:00:00.000
2007-08-12 00:00:00.000
2007-08-13 00:00:00.000
2007-08-14 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're using `MONTH(Orderid)` rather than `MONTH(OrderDate)` ?

Comment: `(MONTH(o.orderid)`???

Comment: jesus, i totally missed that :/
anyhow, I can't delete it anymore because it has answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the wrong parameter into the MONTH() function it should be

```
SELECT
  o.orderdate
FROM Sales.Orders o
WHERE (YEAR(o.orderdate) IN (2007, 2008))
  AND (MONTH(o.orderdate) IN (1, 2, 3))
 ORDER BY o.orderdate;
```

Alternatively, if you are selecting for dates in a date range it is best practice to use inequalities with the full date

```
SELECT
  o.orderdate
FROM Sales.Orders o
WHERE (o.orderdate < '2007-01-01' AND o.orderdate < '2007-03-01')
  OR (o.orderdate < '2008-01-01' AND o.orderdate < '2008-03-01')
 ORDER BY o.orderdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be `orderdate` instead of `orderid`?

```
SELECT
o.orderdate
FROM Sales.Orders o
WHERE (YEAR(o.orderdate) IN (2007, 2008))
  AND (MONTH(o.orderdate) IN (1, 2, 3))
ORDER BY o.orderdate;
```